# After HttpPost, returning a View (ActionResult) when Model is not valid, the response has content type of application/json

Tags: json, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, actionresult, jsonresult

I'm running into a strange issue in more than one page of my ASP.NET MVC site.  When I POST a form and the Model is NOT valid, I try to return the same view so that I can see the errors - however, instead of the page getting reloaded, I get a pop-up download box that says that the file is in "application/json" format.  As you can see from the code below, the controller method returns an ActionResult and NOT a JsonResult:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        var isValid = IsUserAuthenticated(model);
        if (isValid)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return User.IsInRole("Administrator")
                           ? RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin")
                           : RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

When I submit my form without filling it out, I can see that the Model fails validation (correctly), but when it reaches the last line "return View(model);" - it returns all the HTML that I expect - but the content type is set to "application/json".  I don't set the content-type anywhere in my code - so I can't figure out why this happening.  The same thing is happening on other pages as well, so I'm thinking that there's some fundamental thing that I'm doing wrong - but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if this helps or not - but this seems to common across my project.  I have another controller method (also accepting HttpPost ONLY), that I have the same issue with... but it's ONLY when "ModelState.IsValid" is false.  I've tried including the actual view name in the return statement:

return View("LogOn", model);

But that doesn't change anything.  Also, because I'm not handling the JSON - I get a pop-up box from the browser asking if I want to download the response.  If I do, I see my page's HTML, along with the errors messages that I was hoping to see.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue... it was an error introduced by me, I'm embarrassed to say.  However, it's a really easy mistake to make, so I wanted to document the issue here in case anyone else encounters it.  It was all caused because of an "Html.RenderAction(..)" call that I was using on the "Site.Master" page.  That action returns a JsonResult - and if the original post I was trying to do encountered errors - then the action that returns the JsonResult would also execute as soon as the master page was loaded - thus causing this issue.

I ended up removing the "Html.RenderAction(...)" call - and just hard coded the HTML I needed there.

Hope that helps